# Averaging column values for specific sections of data corresponding to other column values in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have a table as follows

```
Name    Points 
sam     25 
sam     43
sam     44
john    27
john    93
scott   82
scott   45
john    21
john    57
john    33
```

I want the output as follows

```
name    points
----    ------
sam      37.33
john     60
scott    63.5
john     37
```

So in the output table i want the value to be printed for every name change in the name column along with the average points for that name.

Comment: And what column indicates the order of the records?

Comment: IMHO OP just needs SELECT Name, AVG(Points) from Table GROUP BY Name

Comment: I don't want to group by the name. I want to group whenever the name changes in the name column.. See the output 'John' appears twice in the output. If i group by name it would appear just once. That's the catch

Comment: @OrsonDCunha In SQL, by definition there is no (inherent) order to the rows. So you can't group by "when it changes", since that is inherently dependent on the order.

Comment: If you don't have a column to order by, then what you want is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the comments, you have to have a way to order the data.  I've mocked up a similar dataset only with an IDENTITY field to provide an ordering of the data, as in the data is inserted in a certain order.  I create a table store the averages as we iterate through the data, aggregating only the range, by name, before the name changes.

The loop is designed to find the specified range and then perform a simple aggregation.  Enjoy.

```
    --Create the main table with an IDENTITY field
    IF OBJECT_ID('tbl_Points','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE tbl_Points;

    CREATE TABLE tbl_Points
    (
          PtID INT IDENTITY
        , Name VARCHAR(255)
        , Points INT
    ); 

    INSERT tbl_Points
    VALUES('sam'  ,25)
         ,('sam'  ,43)
         ,('sam'  ,44)
         ,('john' ,27)
         ,('john' ,93)
         ,('scott',82)
         ,('scott',45)
         ,('john' ,21)
         ,('john' ,57)
         ,('john' ,33);

    --Creae a table to store the averages as we iterate through the main dataset
    IF OBJECT_ID('tbl_AvgPoints','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE tbl_AvgPoints;

    CREATE TABLE tbl_AvgPoints
    (
          Name VARCHAR(255)
        , AVGPoints Numeric(10,4)
    ); 

    --Create and initialize the variables
    DECLARE 
          @ptName VARCHAR(255)
        , @minPt INT
        , @maxPT INT
        , @maxRow INT

    SET @ptName= ''
    SET @minPt = 0
    SET @maxPT = 0

    --get the max row count for the dataset
    SELECT @maxRow=COUNT(1) FROM tbl_Points

    --loop through the data until there is nothing left
    WHILE @maxPT < @maxRow
    BEGIN

        --set the bottom of the range to be aggregated
        SELECT @minPt=MIN(PtID)
        FROM tbl_Points
        WHERE PtID > @maxPT

        --set the name
        SELECT @ptName=Name
        FROM tbl_Points 
        WHERE PtID = @minPt

        --Set the starting point to figure out the top of the range
        SET @maxPT=@minPt

        --Check each record for the name until it changes
        WHILE @ptName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN   

            --stop checking if we have reached the last record
            IF @maxPT=@maxRow
                SET @ptName = NULL
            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                --found the top of the range when the name changes
                IF  (SELECT Name FROM tbl_Points WHERE PtID = @maxPT) <> @ptName
                BEGIN
                    SET @ptName = NULL
                    SET @maxPT = @maxPT-1
                END
                ELSE
                    SET @maxPT = @maxPT+1
            END
        END

        --Use the bottom and top ranges to aggregate on name
        INSERT tbl_AvgPoints
        SELECT Name, AVG(CAST(Points AS NUMERIC(10,4))) AvgPoints
        FROM tbl_Points
        WHERE PtID BETWEEN @minPt AND @maxPT
        GROUP BY Name

    END

    SELECT * FROM tbl_AvgPoints
```

Comment: thanks a lot  @steve mangiameli...This is what i was looking for...:)